# Using Google's libphonenumber library for validation international mobile number without region

Tags: libphonenumber

I'm trying to validate an international mobile number.

For example: **"+972523254545"**.

Afaik, this number should be valid everywhere.

But this library requires "region" too. why is that and how can I overcome it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**region** should not be a required field.  It is not used for phone numbers with a leading '+'.  Without specifying a region I can parse that number in the python version:

```
>>> import phonenumbers

>>> phonenumbers.parse('+972523254545')
PhoneNumber(country_code=972, national_number=523254545, extension=None, italian_leading_zero=None, number_of_leading_zeros=None, country_code_source=None, preferred_domestic_carrier_code=None)
```

And that number parses fine without specifying a region [on their demo page](https://rawgit.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/master/javascript/i18n/phonenumbers/demo-compiled.html).

---

If you really *must* speficy a region, then just stick any region in there.  It's going to be ignored because the leading "+" in the number indicates that it's lead by an international calling code.